# How te send pscp code in java

Tags: java, pscp

I have a problem i want to  send code pscp   like that in java program i wanna send this code root@1xx.2xx.3X.1x:/usr/local/se/log c:/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can run native scripts inside a Java program using the Runtime class:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pscp.exe C:\xm root@1xx.2xx.3X.1x:/usr/local/se/log ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the code. Also check the correct syntax of the pscp command: pscp.exe /help

Comment: okey i wanna run pscp in cmd screen  i wanna send this code in command.exe how to ? pscp C:\xm root@172.168.14.25:/usr/local/se/log/*.*

Comment: See my updated code. Have you tried compiling and running it? I already told you that the Runtime class can execute cmd.exe commands. If you think it is the correct solution mark it as the appropriate answer.

Comment: Firstly i open pscp.exe like this C:/pscp.exe after we can need this code root@192.168.0.1:/usr/local/se/log/*.*   but i cant.. !  :/

Comment: i solved @jovit.royeca  thank you for help :))  class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pscp.exe C:\xm root@1xx.2xx.3X.1x:/usr/local/se/log ");
    }
}

Comment: I'm glad my code helped you. Mark it  as the appropriate answer then.